# How can I paste an image from clipboard directly to a file?

Tags: images, file-manager, screenshot

I need exactly [this one](https://superuser.com/q/212770/187576) but on Linux:

> Anyone know of a way to simply paste a screenshot (taken with PrtScn or Alt+PrtScn) into a Windows Explorer folder and have it be saved as an image (possibly with a dialog asking about image size and format options)? That is, I might take a screenshot with print screen, open a folder and hit Ctrl+V, and a new jpg (or png, or whatever) would appear in that folder with the contents of my screenshot.

Comment: Have a look at `xclip`. You may have to set the target format.

Comment: `xclip` seems to be a useful tool, but it doesn't cover such cases.

Comment: @muru Yes, actually it does answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a small script using `zenity`, `xclip` and `convert`.

Start with this, but note that it is yet very basic, and will overwrite  `clip.png` whenever you run it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
size=$(zenity --list --title "Select target size" --column=size original 2560 1920 1280 640)
if [ size = original ]; then
    xclip -selection c -o -t image/png > clip.png
else
    xclip -selection c -o -t image/png | convert -resize $size\> - clip.png
fi
```

For integration with your file-manager, you could check `nautilus-actions` or alike.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `xclip` and `xdotools`

   ```
   sudo apt install xclip xdotools
   ```
2. Create an executable file, place it wherever you want with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   xdotool key ctrl+r
   xdotool key ctrl+l
   xdotool key ctrl+c
   xdotool key 0xff1b

   dir=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
   # here the path to your Images folder
   img_dir="/home/user/Images/"
   img=$(ls -t "$img_dir" | head -n 1)
   cp "$img_dir$img" "$dir/$img"
   ```
3. Create a keyboard shortcut for the file.
4. Press the screen print key. Then press your shortcut.

---

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with Nautilus, Nemo and Thunar.